# How to make rect's disappear and re-appear using onclick buttons

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have some rectangles that I want to appear and then disappear using onclick buttons. However, the rect's never disappear.

I coded it so that when a certain button is pressed, some variables would either `.hide()` or `.show()`

My logic was that in `go1()` all variables were defined, so that when `go2()` played out, the computer would already know what `r1.remove()` was referring to and therefore hide it, vice versa with `.show()`. This is obviously not the case.

```html
<button id="d" style="width:5em;height:3em;" onclick="go1">click me</button>
        <button id="b" style="width:5em;height:2em;" onclick="go2">click me</button>
        <button id = "a" style="width:5em;height:3em;" onclick="go3">click me2</button>
```

```
var p = Raphael(0, 0, 800, 800);

function go1() {
    let r1 = p.rect(300, 300, 50, 50)
        .attr({
            'fill': 'red',
            'cursor': 'pointer',
            'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
        });
    let r2 = p.rect(377, 300, 50, 50)
        .attr({
            'fill': 'blue',
            'cursor': 'pointer',
            'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
        });
    p.path("M362 162 L588 559");
    //p.path("M10 30L60 30L10 80L60 80z");

    let r3 = p.rect(477, 400, 50, 50)
        .attr({
            'fill': 'yellow',
            'cursor': 'pointer',
            'href': 'https://www.google.com/',
        });
};

function go2() {
    r1.show();
    r2.hide();
    r3.hide();
}

function go3() {
    r1.hide();
    r2.show();
    r3.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you define `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` in `go1` so they are undefined in `go2` and `go3`.

One solution would be to add

`let r1, r2, r3;`

above all functions and then within `go1` change

`let r1 =` to `r1 =` and do the same for the other two `r` variables.

Also I think you need to change `onclick="go1"` to `onclick="go1()"` and do the same for the other two click handlers.

---

I'd highly recommend fixing your indentation. Good indentation makes problems like this much easier to see. If you find it hard to indent your code properly, try using https://beautifier.io/.